# Derivative of the minimiser of convex optimization problem with respect to a parameter

Tags: derivatives, reference-request, convex-optimization, reference-works

I consider a bivariate function $f : \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x,\cdot)$ is strictly convex for any $x$. The strict convexity implies that

$$ y^*(x) = \arg \min_{y \in \mathbb{R}} f(x,y) $$

is uniquely defined for any $x \in \mathbb{R}$. I am curious to know if formulas for the derivatives of $y^*$ exists (together with conditions on $f$ ensuring the existence of derivatives of $y^*$). The problem seems very natural but I could not find easily some elementary or introductive answer to my question.

I am also interested in multivariate or even infinite-dimensional generalizations.

Comment: If we assume that $f$ and $y^*$ are smooth, then we have $\frac{\partial f(x, y^*(x))}{\partial y} = 0$ for all $x$. Now we can differentiate both sides of this equation with respect to $x$ and solve for $(y^*)’(x)$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. To finish the argument, we end up with $(y^*)'(x) = - \partial_{xy} f (x, y^*(x)) / \partial_{yy} f(x,y^*(x))$, this being well defined since $\partial_{yy} f(x,y^*(x)) > 0$ by strict convexity.

Comment: This also suggest that $y^*$ is differentiable as soon as $f$ is $\mathcal{C}^2$.